# Splitting up the value of an XML Element into two, then group them

Tags: php, arrays, xml, foreach

I need some help. It seems so simple, but I can't get it done right. 
Here's the structure of my XML

```
<events> 
 <Show ID="1">
  <Time>2013-01-05 17:30:00</Time>
 </Show>
 <Show ID="2">
  <Time>2013-01-05 20:30:00</Time>
 </Show>
 <Show ID="3">
  <Time>2013-01-06 17:30:00</Time>
 </Show>
 <Show ID="4">
  <Time>2013-01-06 20:30:00</Time>
 </Show>
 <Show ID="5">
  <Time>2013-01-06 21:30:00</Time>
 </Show>
 <Show ID="6">
  <Time>2013-01-07 15:30:00</Time>
 </Show>
</events>
```

Now what I need to do, is to split up the "Time" Element into two values: Date and Time:

```
<?php $xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
foreach (  $xml->Show as $Show ) 
    { 
    // ...
    foreach     (  $Show->Time as $Date )
        {
        $Timecon = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $Date);
        $day = date_format($Timecon, 'd.m.');
        $hours = date_format($Timecon, 'H:i');
        }
    }

?>
```

I spare you the rest of the code, because I actually scrapped it - it was wrong anyways, plus I'm a noob:
Formatting the $Date into $day and $hours works perfectly fine, but as to grouping - whatever I do, **this is what I get:**

05.01. 17:30
05.01. 20:30
06.01. 17:30
06.01. 20:30
06.01. 21:30
07.01. 15:30

and ***this is what I need***, because the XML can get quite long:

05.01. 17:30 20:30
06.01. 17:30 20:30 21:30
07.01. 15:30

As you can see I want the $hours to be grouped by $day or rather have every duplicate-$day skipped/deleted.
I would prefer to do this with PHP, not with XSL.

And yes, I googled for hours and feel really stupid for not getting it. Thanks for you help!

Comment: I provided an answer which clarifies some date manipulation stuff, but not sure I understand what you are trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array to store the values in.

```
$group = array();

foreach( $Show->Time as $Date ) {

    $_date = new DateTime( $Date );

    //if this is a new day, add it to the group
    if( ! isset($group[$_date->format('m.d')]) )
        $group[ $_date->format('m.d') ] = array();

    //add the time to the array, organized by month.day
    $group[ $_date->format('m.d') ][] = $_date->format('H:i');

}

//now you can iterate through the array to print everything out by day/time
foreach( $group as $month => $times ) {
    echo $month . ': <br />';
    foreach( $times as $time ) {
        echo $time . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this still puts out: 
01.05: 17:30  
01.05: 20:30  
01.06: 20:30  
01.06: 21:30  
01.07: 20:30  
other than
01.05: 17:30 20:30  
01.06: 20:30 21:30  
01.07: 20:30

Comment: Yes, it puts that out because I what I spit out as an example. Try `print_r($group)`. You can iterate over the array and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: finally works! see my comment below. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty array outside of both of the foreach loops.

```
$grouped = array();
```

Then after you create your variables..

```
$day = date_format($Timecon, 'd.m.');
$hours = date_format($Timecon, 'H:i')....
```

Then push the date as a key and the hours as a value.

```
$grouped[$day] = $hours;
```

Then when you dump the array, you'll have an array that looks something like this:

```
Array(
    [5.01] = Array(
        String [5] = '17:30',
        String [5] = '20:30'
    ),
    [6.01] = Array(
        String [5] = '17:30',
        String [5] = '20:30'
    ),
);
```

And so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I used Chris' suggestion with a minor change and it works, thank you!

```
$group = array();

  foreach ( $xml->Show as $Show ) { 

          foreach( $Show->Time as $Date ) {

              $_date = new DateTime( $Date );

              //if this is a new day, add it to the group
              if( ! isset($group[$_date->format('m.d')]) )
                  $group[ $_date->format('m.d') ] = array();

              //add the time to the array, organized by month.day
              $group[ $_date->format('m.d') ][] = $_date->format('H:i');
          }

      }
      foreach( $group as $month => $times ) { echo $month . ': <br />';
              foreach( $times as $time ) {  echo $time . '<br />'; }
              }
  }
```

now it will look like this

```
Array
(
    [01.05] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17:30
            [1] => 20:30
        )

    [01.06] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20:30
            [1] => 21:30
        )

    [01.07] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20:30
        )

)
```

bam! Thank you guys!